# Redirect subfolder to subfolder and remove subfolder via nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, directory

I'm trying to redirect a subfolder to another subfolder with nginx. The hard part is removing the target subfolder from displaying, as it's a ruby app and not a true root folder. They are both on the same server, and I obviously control both domains

Example:
www.example1.com/example
redirects to
www.example2.com

Furthest I've made it, although I know it's not right..

```
if ($request_uri ~* ^\/example) {
rewrite ^\/example  http://example.com permanent;
}
```

It is important to remember that there is no physical root.